# Not able to extract Content from IhttpActionResult ,Getting error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, moq, rest

I have a controller that populates some random list and I combine that list in a `Response` object with a message. following is the controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
    [Authorize]
    [Route(RouteConfig.Routes.LovList.contactStatus)]
    public IHttpActionResult ContactStatusList()
    {
        try
        {
            var result = _herodb.GetList(
                            DBClass.DBConstants.ListConstants.query_Contact_Status);
            return Ok(new Models.Response(
                        Models.ResponseMessages.Success,
                        result)
                     );
        }
        catch(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException)
        {
            return InternalServerError();
        }
        catch(System.Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Error(ex, ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
            return InternalServerError();
        }
        
    }
```

When I tried to **UNIT TEST** this controller I mocked my DB function `GetList` successfully which returning a dummy list. But in the unit test method I unable to extract Content from IhttpActionResult.
Here is my test method.

```
[TestMethod()]
    public void ContactStatusListTest_ShouldReturnData_WhenCalled()
    {
        //Arrange
        Mock<DBClass.IHerodb> mock = new Mock<DBClass.IHerodb>();

        mock.Setup(x => x.GetList(DBClass.DBConstants.ListConstants.query_Contact_Status))
            .Returns(CreateContactList());

        //Act
        IHttpActionResult result =new ListController(mock.Object).ContactStatusList();
        // JsonResult<IHttpActionResult> json = result.
        var res = result as OkNegotiatedContentResult<List<object>>;
       // var res = result as JsonResult<List<object>>;
        Models.Response response= res.Content[0] as Models.Response;

        //Assert
        Assert.IsNotInstanceOfType(result, typeof(NotFoundResult));
        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result, typeof(OkResult));
        Assert.AreEqual(response.Message, Models.ResponseMessages.Success);
        Assert.IsNotNull(response.Data);
    }
    public System.Data.DataTable CreateContactList()
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("ContactStatus");
        DataRow row1 = table.NewRow();row1["ContactStatus"] = "Contacted"; table.Rows.Add(row1);
        DataRow row2 = table.NewRow(); row2["ContactStatus"] = "Not Contacted"; table.Rows.Add(row2);
        DataRow row3 = table.NewRow(); row3["ContactStatus"] = "Contacted"; table.Rows.Add(row3);
        return table;
    }
```

I am getting follwing response in **result** variable .
[image]

Please suggest some methods to extract the content of the response. I tried both **JsonResult** or **OkNegotiatedContentResult**. But no luck. Both returning NULL. Please help I am stuck

Answer (score 0):

I have tried everything until i come up with `XUNIT` framework. XUnit framework solved the issue. As well as it provide great benefits.Installed follwing
**NugetPackages**
`xunit`
`xunit.runner`
`xunit.runner.console`